Marginal effect of poisson regression with interaction
I have difficulties to understand the result from {marginaleffects} package in R with Poisson regression.
If I do:
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * as.factor(gear), data = mtcars)
summary(mod)

I get:
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         25.307903   2.650811   9.547 5.51e-10 ***
hp                  -0.052240   0.014560  -3.588 0.001356 ** 
as.factor(gear)4    15.262616   3.862728   3.951 0.000531 ***
as.factor(gear)5     7.469550   3.805534   1.963 0.060451 .  
hp:as.factor(gear)4 -0.126946   0.033574  -3.781 0.000825 ***
hp:as.factor(gear)5 -0.006029   0.019276  -0.313 0.756952    

and avg_comparisons(mod, variables = "hp", by = c("gear")) returns
 Term gear Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 %  97.5 %
   hp    3  -0.0522     0.0146 -3.59   <0.001 11.6 -0.0808 -0.0237
   hp    4  -0.1792     0.0303 -5.92   <0.001 28.2 -0.2385 -0.1199
   hp    5  -0.0583     0.0126 -4.61   <0.001 17.9 -0.0830 -0.0335

Where the first line returns the estimate -0.0522 found in the summary of the model, because I have the same reference. This makes sense to me.
What I don't understand is what happens with Poisson:
mod <- glm(cyl ~ hp * as.factor(gear), data = tmp, family = poison())
summary(mod)

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          1.5599308  0.3891456   4.009 6.11e-05 ***
hp                   0.0025199  0.0020809   1.211    0.226    
as.factor(gear)4    -0.6005544  0.6561946  -0.915    0.360    
as.factor(gear)5    -0.4006457  0.6104003  -0.656    0.512    
hp:as.factor(gear)4  0.0038348  0.0058576   0.655    0.513    
hp:as.factor(gear)5  0.0005107  0.0028537   0.179    0.858 

I would have expected avg_comparisons to return 0.0025199 and then calculate the different values for the different gear values, but:
avg_comparisons(mod, variables = "hp", by = c("gear"))

 Term gear Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)   S    2.5 % 97.5 %
   hp    3   0.0188     0.0157 1.20    0.230 2.1 -0.01189 0.0496
   hp    4   0.0297     0.0260 1.14    0.253 2.0 -0.02125 0.0807
   hp    5   0.0182     0.0122 1.49    0.136 2.9 -0.00573 0.0421

Here, the first line estimate is 0.0188, not 0.0025199, and I don't understand why.

This is because a Poisson regression uses the exponential function by default to link the linear predictor to the response's expected value, which is nonlinear. Therefore, the coefficients are on the "log" scale. The impact of each predictor on the response expectation is nonlinear, too, and it depends on the values of all other predictors. By default, avg_comparisons() calculates the contrast in the response (not the linear predictor) for each observation (different result from each other) and average them to give mean difference in the response.
You will find coefficients in the model summary and mean contrast to align if you use glm(family = poisson(link = "identity")), which fits a Poisson regression with an identity link. Alternatively, you can let avg_comparisons() estimate the linear predictor instead by avg_comparisons(type = "link") and find the mean contrast equal to reported model coefficients.
